# Amazon getting Orders of seller

Tags: amazon-web-services

The question is, Is it possible to get the orders of an Amazon Seller only given their Id and Password? As far as I understand it requires the use of MWS which in turn requires the seller to be eligible for MWS. Is it possible to avoid MWS and simply login using an Id and Passsword? A quick answer would be very helpful. Thank you, Regards.

Comment: Asking people for their amazon credentials would be against policies.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I do not need the person's credentials I just need a way of getting the orders of the person. I am developing an application that needs to check orders of 10 set accounts.